# Reordering groups of rows in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm doing some user studies and everyone is given parts in different orders. The data looks a little like this. Currently importing all into a datatable:

```
Question 3
1        6
2        9

Question 1
1        2
3        5

Question 2
2        5
1        2
```

I now have multiple CSV files with each 'question' row in different orders.
Can I search for the 'question' rows, group them with everything between each 'question' and put them in order? There will be multiple lines between, and we don't know how many exactly.
So it would look like this

```
Question 1
1        2
3        5 

Question 2
2        5
1        2

Question 3
1        6
2        9
```

Comment: Is that what a raw file looks like? If not and that's supposed to represent a `data.frame`, please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput`. Thanks!

Comment: It's not exactly what the raw looks like, but the raw data is far too long to be put here. This is just a rough representation of my raw files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the file is your first step, ordering from there should be rather direct with `order` or `dplyr::arrange`.

```r
txt <- readLines("quux.txt")
txt
# [1] "Question 3" "1        6" "2        9" "Question 1" "1        2" "3        5" "Question 2" "2        5" "1        2"

lst_of_frames <- lapply(
  split(txt, cumsum(grepl("^Question", txt))),
  function(z) {
    out <- read.table(header = FALSE, text = z[-1])
    cbind(question = z[1], out)
  })
lst_of_frames
# $`1`
#     question V1 V2
# 1 Question 3  1  6
# 2 Question 3  2  9
# $`2`
#     question V1 V2
# 1 Question 1  1  2
# 2 Question 1  3  5
# $`3`
#     question V1 V2
# 1 Question 2  2  5
# 2 Question 2  1  2
```

We now have a list of multiple frames. If you want them combined, then multiple options exist:

```r
results <- do.call(rbind, lst_of_frames)
results
#       question V1 V2
# 1.1 Question 3  1  6
# 1.2 Question 3  2  9
# 2.1 Question 1  1  2
# 2.2 Question 1  3  5
# 3.1 Question 2  2  5
# 3.2 Question 2  1  2
dplyr::bind_rows(lst_of_frames)        # similar results
data.table::rbindlist(lst_of_frames)   # similar results
```

I'll use the results from the first, and then order with

```r
results[order(results$question, results$V1),]
#       question V1 V2
# 2.1 Question 1  1  2
# 2.2 Question 1  3  5
# 3.2 Question 2  1  2
# 3.1 Question 2  2  5
# 1.1 Question 3  1  6
# 1.2 Question 3  2  9
dplyr::arrange(results, question, V1)  # similar results
```

Note: this is sensitive to the number of columns within each question. If there are different number of columns ...

```
Question 3
1        6
2        9

Question 1
1        2       10
3        5       11

Question 2
2        5
1        2
```

Then you have some options.

1. **Keep it wide.** The simple base R `do.call(rbind,...)` no longer works as easily:

   ```r
   do.call(rbind, lst_of_frames)
   # Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
   #   numbers of columns of arguments do not match
   ```

   But the others work fine:

   ```r
   dplyr::bind_rows(lst_of_frames)
   #     question V1 V2 V3
   # 1 Question 3  1  6 NA
   # 2 Question 3  2  9 NA
   # 3 Question 1  1  2 10
   # 4 Question 1  3  5 11
   # 5 Question 2  2  5 NA
   # 6 Question 2  1  2 NA
   data.table::rbindlist(lst_of_frames, fill = TRUE)  # similar results
   ```
2. **Pivot to long.** (This is a "wide-vs-long" data discussion.)

   ```r
   dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(lst_of_frames, function(z) tidyr::pivot_longer(z, -question)))
   # # A tibble: 14 x 3
   #    question   name  value
   #    <chr>      <chr> <int>
   #  1 Question 3 V1        1
   #  2 Question 3 V2        6
   #  3 Question 3 V1        2
   #  4 Question 3 V2        9
   #  5 Question 1 V1        1
   #  6 Question 1 V2        2
   #  7 Question 1 V3       10
   #  8 Question 1 V1        3
   #  9 Question 1 V2        5
   # 10 Question 1 V3       11
   # 11 Question 2 V1        2
   # 12 Question 2 V2        5
   # 13 Question 2 V1        1
   # 14 Question 2 V2        2

   # similar results
   library(data.table)
   rbindlist(lapply(lst_of_frames, function(z) melt(as.data.table(z), id = "question")))
   ```

   This method has several advantages in other realms (e.g., `ggplot2`, tidy data management, easy summarization, etc).

---